# Execute a Perl script from R

Tags: r, perl, csv

I need to execute a Perl program as part of a larger R program.

The R code generates a series of output files with different extensions, for instance `.out` or `.lis`.

I have a Perl program that converts those files to CSV.

I've seen Perl arguments executed on R, but nothing with this complexity.

```
@outfiles = glob( "*.lis" );

foreach $outfile ( @outfiles ) {

    print $outfile, "\n";

    $outfile =~ /(\S+)lis$/;
    $csvfile = $1 . "lis.csv";
    print $csvfile, "\n";

    open( OUTFILE, "$outfile" )  || die "ERROR: Unable to open $outfile\n";
    open( CSVFILE, ">$csvfile" ) || die "ERROR: Unable to open $csvfile\n";

    $lineCnt = 0;

    while ( $outline = <OUTFILE> ) {
        chomp( $outline );

        $lineCnt++;

        $outline =~ s/^\s+//;    # Remove whitespace at the beginning of the line
        if ( $lineCnt == 1 ) {
            $outline =~ s/,/\./g;    # Replace all the commas with periods in the hdr line
        }

        $outline =~ s/\s+/,/g;       # Replace remaining whitespace delimiters with a comma
        print CSVFILE "$outline\n";
    }

    close( OUTFILE );
    close( CSVFILE );
}
```

Is there any way I can integrate the Perl code into my R code? I could develop an R program that does the same. But I wouldn't know where to start to convert a `.lis` or `.out` file to `.csv`.

Comment: Add the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/perl`) and make the file executable. Then, it just becomes a question of a launching an executable from R.

Comment: That's a horrible way to generate CSV. Use Text::CSV_XS. (And if the input is really a tab-separated file, you should also use Text::CSV_XS to parse the input!)

Comment: My comments have nothing to do with your question, so no, I can't elaborate. If you want your code reviewed, there's a StackExchange site where you can do that. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *"nothing with this complexity."* It's thirty lines!!

Answer (score 1):

Call it by using R's system call:

```
my.seed <- as.numeric(try(system(" perl -e 'print int(rand(1000000))'", intern = TRUE))) #get random number :D
```

However, I must agree with @ikegami, there are better modules to handle CSV data.