# having R print a system call that contains "", '', and escape character \

Tags: r, escaping, quotes

I need to run a perl command from within an R script. I would normally do this via:

```
system(paste0('my command'))
```

However, the command I want to paste contains both single and double quotes and an escape character. Specifically, I would like to paste this command:

```
perl -pe '/^>/ ? print "\n" : chomp' in.fasta | tail -n +2 > out.fasta
```

I have tried escaping the double quotes with more escape characters, which allows me to pass the command, but it then prints all 3 escape characters, which causes the command to fail. Is there a good way around this, such that I can save the above perl line as a string in R, that I can then pass to the `system()` function?

Comment: Have you tried [`shQuote`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/shQuote.html)?

Comment: @r2evans played with `shQuote`, but it didn't get me where I needed to go (though this could be my fault).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I haven't tested your particular `perl` call (since it involves particular file/directory etc) but tried something trivial by escaping the quotes and it seems to work. You might want to refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193433/execute-a-perl-script-from-r) question for more as well.
My approach,

```
# shouldnt have any text expect for an empty string
my_text <- try(system(" perl -e 'print \"\n\"' ", intern = TRUE))
my_text

[1] ""


# should contain the string - Hello perl from R!
my_text2 <- try(system(" perl -e 'print \"Hello perl from R!\"' ", intern = TRUE))
my_text2

[1] "Hello perl from R!"
```

So based on the above trials I think this should work for you -

```
try(system(command = "perl -pe '/^>/ ? print \"\n\" : chomp' in.fasta | tail -n +2 > out.fasta", intern = TRUE))
```

Note - `intern = TRUE` just captures the output as a character vector in R.

Comment: oh man this is most promising. I need to edit a few more things to test in a more complex case to see if this generalizes...

Comment: Deleting my answer, but if the raw string doesn't work, try the unicode string `'perl -pe \U0027/\U005E>/ ? print "\\n" : chomp\U0027 in.fasta | tail -n +2 > out.fasta'` following the above.

Comment: ok, this sort of works, but I want to drop in place of `in.fasta` a item from a vector, which is why I was using `paste0`. So I could do something like `paste0('chomp ',sample.list[1],' tail -n...')`

Comment: How about a little `sprintf()` action? `sprintf("perl -pe \U0027/\U005E>/ ? print : chomp\U0027 in.fasta | tail -n +2 > %s","fileName")`

Comment: ok this does work if I wrap the quotes with `paste0`, which allows me to drop in text stored in R vectors!